# Sub Total on Google Sheet Pivot Table Shows the Wrong Sum

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, calculated-field

So, I made a pivot table with calculated formula in google sheets
but somehow, the subtotal for each client was shown wrong

the code for Total Income I've been using is this one;

`=IF((business_initiated+user_initiated)>=1000;($C$4*business_initiated+$D$4*user_initiated);0)`

the code for Total Invoice I've been using is this one;

`=IF((business_initiated+user_initiated)>=1000;IF(($C$5*business_initiated+$D$5*user_initiated)<0;0;($C$5*business_initiated+$D$5*user_initiated));500000)`

| client | month | Total Business Initiated | Total IDR | Total User Initiated | Total IDR | Total Message | Total Income | Total Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3.880 | Rp1.437.462 | 668 | Rp0 | 4.548 | Rp454.800 | Rp1.805.397 |
| A | 2 | 3.416 | Rp1.265.560 | 550 | Rp0 | 3.966 | Rp396.600 | Rp1.568.500 |
| A | 3 | 6.007 | Rp2.225.473 | 699 | Rp0 | 6.706 | Rp670.600 | Rp2.610.483 |
| A | 4 | 4.473 | Rp1.657.157 | 645 | Rp0 | 5.118 | Rp511.800 | Rp2.012.423 |
| A | 5 | 15.292 | Rp5.665.380 | 2.380 | Rp1.310.904 | 17.672 | Rp1.767.200 | Rp6.976.284 |
| A | 6 | 15.898 | Rp5.889.891 | 914 | Rp0 | 16.812 | Rp1.681.200 | Rp6.393.322 |
| Total |  | 48.966 | Rp18.140.924 | 5.856 | Rp3.225.485 | 54.822 | Rp5.482.200 | Rp21.366.408 |
| B | 5 | 0 | Rp0 | 569 | Rp0 | 569 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| B | 6 | 1.749 | Rp647.970 | 1.400 | Rp771.120 | 3.149 | Rp314.900 | Rp1.419.090 |
| Total |  | 1.749 | Rp647.970 | 1.969 | Rp1.084.525 | 3.718 | Rp371.800 | Rp1.732.495 |
| C | 1 | 0 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| C | 2 | 0 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| C | 3 | 0 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| C | 4 | 0 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| Total |  | 0 | Rp0 | 4 | Rp0 | 4 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |

Here are the expected results;

| client | month | Total Business Initiated | Total IDR | Total User Initiated | Total IDR | Total Message | Total Income | Total Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3.880 | Rp1.437.462 | 668 | Rp0 | 4.548 | Rp454.800 | Rp1.805.397 |
| A | 2 | 3.416 | Rp1.265.560 | 550 | Rp0 | 3.966 | Rp396.600 | Rp1.568.500 |
| A | 3 | 6.007 | Rp2.225.473 | 699 | Rp0 | 6.706 | Rp670.600 | Rp2.610.483 |
| A | 4 | 4.473 | Rp1.657.157 | 645 | Rp0 | 5.118 | Rp511.800 | Rp2.012.423 |
| A | 5 | 15.292 | Rp5.665.380 | 2.380 | Rp1.310.904 | 17.672 | Rp1.767.200 | Rp6.976.284 |
| A | 6 | 15.898 | Rp5.889.891 | 914 | Rp0 | 16.812 | Rp1.681.200 | Rp6.393.322 |
| Total |  | 48.966 | Rp18.140.924 | 5.856 | Rp3.225.485 | 54.822 | Rp5.482.200 | Rp21.366.408 |
| B | 5 | 0 | Rp0 | 569 | Rp0 | 569 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| B | 6 | 1.749 | Rp647.970 | 1.400 | Rp771.120 | 3.149 | Rp314.900 | Rp1.419.090 |
| Total |  | 1.749 | Rp647.970 | 1.969 | Rp1.084.525 | 3.718 | Rp371.800 | Rp1.919.090 |
| C | 1 | 0 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| C | 2 | 0 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| C | 3 | 0 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| C | 4 | 0 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | 1 | Rp0 | Rp500.000 |
| Total |  | 0 | Rp0 | 4 | Rp0 | 4 | Rp0 | Rp2000.000 |

So, basically if the total message for each month is less than 1000. The income income will be Rp0 and Total Invoice will be Rp500000.

But somehow the sub-total wasn't displayed correctly if the Total Income is 0 and Total Invoice is Rp500000.

Does anyone had idea how to solve this problem? Thank you so much.

Edit (Solved):
I believe we couldn't do a more complex formula inside the Pivot Table calculated field. So, instead of using complex formula inside the Pivot Table, applied it outside the pivot then work around the problem.

Comment: Share a copy of your sheet. Probably have issue with display format.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't share the sheet, since it's private data. Can you explain more about the display format?

Comment: If you cannot share a copy as is, please anonymize it and / or make at least one minimum and reproducible example. I agree with isfurw.

Comment: I think we can identify the problem with 2 rows. Could you do a flavor? 'Display format' means your value may not be formatted as number but string, so it is regarded as `0` upon calculations.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15he5w1X7uyfKNkvW9hLx-iZnrm7OXa-z9dPfPznk2Ok/edit?usp=sharing i've tried to reproduce the sheet. you can check it if you can, but I can't show the original data to the sheet

Comment: Please make your reproduced sheet accessible for people to check and see how we can help.

Comment: Already done that

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I've created a new column for each income and invoice, respectively. So, in the end, I could use the same principle for the formula. After some digging through, I believe there's something different on the Pivot Table Calculated Field, as you can't do much with the calculation formula.